# Azure Active Directory Error. The access token is from the wrong issuer

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to call a Azure ARM Rest API to create a resource group. I am passing tenant_id, client_id and client_secret to get the access token which will be later used as authorization header. My code is like below. The application ID is the client ID off the application and application secret is the key which is generated after selecting the time duration.

```
import adal
import requests
token_response = adal.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + '<tenantId>',
    '<ApplicationId>',
    '<Application Secret>'
)
access_token = token_response.get('accessToken')

endpoint = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx/resourcegroups/resourcename?api-version=2015-01-01'

headers = {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + access_token}
json_output = requests.put(endpoint,headers=headers).json()
print json_output
```

But this is throwing me an error as below

```
{u'error': {u'message': u"The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts
.windows.net/xxx/'. It must match the tenant 'h
ttps://sts.windows.net/xxx/' associated with th
is subscription. Please use the authority (URL) 'https://login.windows.net/xxx' to get the token. Note, if the subscription is
transferred to another tenant there is no impact to the services, but informatio
n about new tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just tra
nsferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later.",
u'code': u'InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant'}}
```

What does this error mean and am I passing the right credentials. If I use the credentials mentioned in the error, I get another error which says application with mentioned client_id not found.

Comment: What is the value you're passing for "TenantId"?

Comment: I'm passing the string which is in OAuth 2.0 Authorization Endpoint, which is after https://login.windows.net

Comment: The tenant id should either be a GUID or something like `somevalue.onmicrosoft.com` (essentially your Azure AD name). Is that you're providing?

Comment: @Gaurav, `https://manage.windowsazure.com/serco.onmicrosoft.com#Workspaces/ActiveDirectoryExtension/Directory/<Tenant ID GUID>/directoryQuickStart`, this is what I'm passing.

Comment: Please try by using just `serco.onmicrosoft.com`.

Comment: @GauravMantri, I'm getting the error `

{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"AADSTS70001: Applicat
ion with identifier 'xxx' was not found in the
directory sonchno365.onmicrosoft.com`

Comment: There are 2 things you may want to check: 1) What's the directory in which the application is created? Is it sonchno365.onmicrosoft.com? 2) If it is not sonchno365.onmicrosoft.com, then please check if the application is marked as `multi tenant`?

Comment: @shwetha - did you find solution for this?

Comment: @DSA - Yes, a subscription will be mapped to only one active directory and you have to use "tenant ID" of that directory which is mapped to your subscription. In my case I was trying with a directory which was not mapped to my subscription. You can change the settings and make your subscription map to the directory which you want to use.

Comment: @shwetha so did you find a resolution to this problem? Or your'e still facing it (as of the time of this writing) 1 year and two months later?

Answer (score 0):

As the message says you need to go against `login.windows.net` instead of `login.microsoftonline.com`:

```
token_response = adal.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
'https://login.windows.net/' + '<tenantId>',
'<ApplicationId>',
'<Application Secret>'
```

Comment: I don't think that would matter as `login.windows.net` would redirect to `login.microsoftonline.com`. Please see this post: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ad/2015/03/06/simplifying-our-azure-ad-authentication-flows/.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is some problem with your AD application. To authenticate Azure ARM you need a AD with service principal.
You can refer to [Create Active Directory application and service principal using portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/) or [Authenticating a service principal with Azure Resource Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/) to create a new AD application. Use these info in your code and try again.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain how some applications, such as Azure PowerShell and Visual Studio Cloud Explorer, are able to access Azure resources without a Service Principal in my directory.

Answer (score 0):

In client credentials use

```
"https://management.core.windows.net/"
```

instead of `https://login.microsoftonline.com/` in your code.

`token_response = adal.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
 'https://management.core.windows.net/' + '<tenantId>',
 '<ApplicationId>',
 '<Application Secret>'`

I fixed same problem with this.

Thanks,
Bhushan

Answer (score -1):

It's the difference between common tenant and separate tenant which causes this issue.

Would you please see my answer in another thread [Azure Active Directory Authorization "The access token is from the wrong issuer '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270527/azure-active-directory-authorization-the-access-token-is-from-the-wrong-issuer/37291869#37291869) ?

Hope this helps.

Comment: The link in the referenced post is no longer valid.