# Azure Active Directory Authorization "The access token is from the wrong issuer '

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to implement [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219004.aspx) but I'm having an error:

```
{
 "error": {
"code": "InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant",
"message": "The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts.windows.net/id/'. It must match the tenant 'https://sts.windows.net/id/' associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL) 'https://login.windows.net/id' to get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later."
}
}
```

Any help is really appreciated. 
Thanks!!!

Update:
Here's the code:

```
 public static string GetAccessToken()
    {
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/tenant-id");
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: "client-id", clientSecret: "key");
        var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource: "https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential: credential);

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
        }

        string token = result.AccessToken;

        return token;
    }
```

Also, is there an API for pricing calculator? Thanks

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: @JackZeng updated my question. Thanks

Comment: Quick question: `id` you used here `new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/id"` and here `new ClientCredential(clientId: "id", clientSecret: "key");`, are they the same and refer to the `ClientId`?

Comment: The `id` here `var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/id");` should be **tenantId**.

Comment: @GauravMantri no. For the AuthenticationContext, I used the Tenant Id and for the ClientCredential, I used the ClientID

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is : we authenticated against the common tenant, but now we're trying access data from a subscription which belongs to a separate tenant - and we don't have an  AccessToken  for this new tenant.

What we have to do in this case is acquire a new  AccessToken  (a JWT) for the same user and client ID, but authorising against the tenant for the subscription we selected.

i.e. we have an  AccessToken , but it's a common tenant  AccessToken , and therefore is limited in what is authorised: to work with resources that are specific to a particular subscription, we now need an  AccessToken  for that specific subscription and tenant.

To do this, we just need to use the TenantId  of the subscription the User selected instead of using a Tenant of "common".

See the step 3 at http://www.bizbert.com/bizbert/2015/11/16/Listing+Subscriptions+And+Logic+Apps+From+NET.aspx for details.

Comment: The link is no longer valid. :-(